# Cannot compile moses due to old boost version

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I tried to compile moses(one of the statistical machine translation system) following the steps 
specified [here](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted)
I don't have root privileges so I used `wget` to installed newer version of boost. As the documentation above says, I tried to compile moses with the following command.
`./bjam --with-boost=~/bin/boost_1_55_0 -j8`
But it failed, getting following error.
`You have Boost 104100. This package requires Boost at least 104400 (and preferably newer).`

I am not familiar with bjam but my guess is that bjam is referencing the older version of boost even though I specified the location of new version of boost. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Try specifying the full path instead of using ~

Comment: wow... it worked!! thank you^^ do you know why "~" doesn't work?

Comment: ~ doesn't always get expanded - it's a shell thing, so depending on how the path is being processed you may not end up with a valid path. Generally avoid using ~ except in a shell context.